# iOS - Adding highlighter effect to a part of the text

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, uilabel

I would like to accomplish something like this for UILabel: 
[image]

The stroke basically represents a casual highlight of that part of the text using a highlighter.

I thought of using `resizableImageWithCapInsets` and then use it as the background of the text, but it doesn't work with the highlighting artifacts on the top and the bottom edge of the highlight.

My question comes down to:

1. Can I set a background image(?) for a part of the text in a UILabel?
2. What kind of image format should I get to be able to dynamically resize it based on the length of the text that needs to be highlighted?

I have almost gotten it right on Android by playing with SVG points, but I couldn't find a way to do it on iOS.

Comment: You'll need to use CoreText, drawing yourself `UILabel`/`NSAttributedString`, with your custom effects. There is no built in function for that.

Comment: TextKit is your friend with NSLayoutManager, NSTextStorage and NSTextContainer: it's definitely made for this purpose ⇒ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/textkit